# Maximum and minimum of $f(x)=\cos(\sin(x))-\sin(\cos(x))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given the function:
$$f(x)=\cos(\sin(x))-\sin(\cos(x))$$
it has absolute maxima at $x=(2k+1)\pi$ with $k=0,1,..N$ and relative maxima at $x=2k\pi$. It is not clear where are the minima. Putting the derivative to zero doesn't help. Any suggestion on how to find the minimum value and where is it? Thanks.

Comment: The reason why a derivative wouldn't help is because there isn't a defined interval. Are you given a defined interval?

Comment: Hm at least the answer doesn't seem to be a common $\pi$  ratio https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum+of+%5Ccos+%5Cleft(%5Csin+x%5Cright)-%5Csin+%5Cleft(%5Ccos+x%5Cright)

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect this to have a nice closed form? Or would you be happy with a numerical approximation?

Comment: @KingDuken What do you mean? Why do you need an interval?

Comment: Because functions go on forever thus making it hard to find maxima or minima.

Comment: @KingDuken But $\forall x f(x) = f(x+2 \pi)$ so this function has a period of at most $2 \pi$. The fact that the OP told us the maxima occur with a period of $2 \pi$ confirms indeed that the function has a period of exactly $2 \pi$. So if you find the minimum on any interval of length $2 \pi$, you can find the other minimums by adding a arbitrary multiple of $2 \pi$

Comment: The interval could be in $x\in (\dfrac{3\pi}{2},\dfrac{5\pi}{2})$. Obviously, a closed form could be more suitable.

Comment: Hardest question with the algebra-precalculus tag I've seen in a while.  You sure this is algebra-precalculus though?

Comment: @SimpleArt: really, I'm not sure. Maybe 'Calculus' would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function, whose graph is symmetric with respect to $x=\pi$, so it is enough to study $f(x)$ over the interval $[0,\pi]$. We have:

$$ f'(x) = \sin(x)\cos(\cos x)-\cos(x)\sin(\sin x) $$
hence the endpoints of $[0,\pi]$ are for sure stationary points due to the vanishing of $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(\sin x)$. There is a third stationary point inside that interval (an absolute minimum) associated with the solution (unique in $(0,1)$) of a trascendental equation,
$$ \frac{\sin u}{u}=\frac{\cos\sqrt{1-u^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}. $$
Numerically, the first relative mimum occurs at $x_0 \approx 0.69272857$ and
$$ f(x_0)\approx 0.107127,$$
so we have:
$$\boxed{\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\qquad \cos(\sin(x))-\sin(\cos x)\geq \frac{1}{10_{\phantom{}}}.} $$

Comment: What means "associated"? Can x_0 be expressed in terms of that unique u in (0,1) ? (even though it's not easier to solve that equation for u than to minimize f...)